# When sending resume and cover letter in an email, what to put in the email body?

Tags: communication, applications, email, cover-letter

I would like to send my resume and cover letters in an email to a recruiter officer of an employer. I have both resume and cover letters in pdf. But I am not sure what is to say in the email body.

How should I determine what to communicate in the body of an email containing these documents?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Essentially, put the cover letter itself in the body -- this introduces you and lets them know why they are getting the email.  It is ok to add it as an attachment as well, which makes it easier for them to save it, print it, or file it however they need to.  (I would mention in the email that you are attaching the cover letter for this purpose.)

Comment: should I do both?

Comment: @Ooker It's not necessary, but you can if you wish.  Just indicate that you are doing both in the email.