# What should my email say when I'm sending a formal Email for Job?

Tags: job-search, human-resources

Is there anything wrong in this message? Please suggest the changes if there are any to improve this message.

> Dear employer,
>
> Look at my resume and cover letter. It’ll tell you all about me. I
>   really want this job.
>
> Your's Sincerely,
>
> XYZ.

Any good suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: It looks like spam to me.

Comment: We aren't a writing service. I'd suggest editing your question to focus on an answerable question like "*What should my email say when I'm sending in a separately attached resume and cover letter?*".

Comment: @Lilienthal thanks for the advice, I've updated the title please check.

Comment: @RahulHendawe The implication behind that title is that you're not sure what, if anything, the body of the mail should contain as you'd be repeating what you've said in the cover letter that you've chosen to add as an attachment. If that *is* your question you should update the body. If your question is more generic, such as "How do I apply for a job via mail?" then that's a rather trivial question but I suppose it's still on-topic.

Comment: I had a look at the search and your question is probably a duplicate of one of the following: [When applying to a job via e-mail what do you put in the message?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/41872) or [When sending resume and cover letter in an email, what to put in the email body?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13778/). Note that the latter question is closed, suggesting it's not a good question for the site, which the downvotes you're getting also seem to indicate.

Comment: How did you find out about the job opening? Include this information in your message. "I saw the job posting for XXX on YYY".

Answer (score 2):

I would go something like the below

> Dear Employer,
>
> Please find attached my Resume and Cover Letter for position XXX. If you require any more information from me regarding my application for this role then please feel free to contact me.
>
> Kind Regards
>
> XXX

Your email in the question isn't really professional in its tone.